# R filter matrix using dplyr

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, dplyr

I'm trying to to filter a matrix using filter() from `dplyr` package.

```
mtcars_matrix = as.matrix(mtcars)    
mtcars_matrix %>% dplyr::filter(hp>100) # threw an error
```

Below code worked, I wish to not juggle between a matrix and a data.frame

```
mtcars_matrix %>% as.data.frame %>% dplyr::filter(hp>100) %>% as.matrix()
```

Is there any way I can use dplyr to filter `matrices`?

Comment: The only way to get it worked is either convert to data.frame or tibble if you need to use `filter`\

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately `dplyr::filter` only works for data.frame and tibble, as commented by @akrun. One possible solution is to use the `subset` fuction.

```
df <- mtcars_matrix %>% 
  base::subset(mtcars_matrix[,"hp"] > 100)
df
```

```
> df
                     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Hornet 4 Drive      21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
Valiant             18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
Duster 360          14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
Merc 280            19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4
Merc 280C           17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4
Merc 450SE          16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3
Merc 450SL          17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3
Merc 450SLC         15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3
Cadillac Fleetwood  10.4   8 472.0 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4
Lincoln Continental 10.4   8 460.0 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4
Chrysler Imperial   14.7   8 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4
Dodge Challenger    15.5   8 318.0 150 2.76 3.520 16.87  0  0    3    2
AMC Javelin         15.2   8 304.0 150 3.15 3.435 17.30  0  0    3    2
Camaro Z28          13.3   8 350.0 245 3.73 3.840 15.41  0  0    3    4
Pontiac Firebird    19.2   8 400.0 175 3.08 3.845 17.05  0  0    3    2
Lotus Europa        30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2
Ford Pantera L      15.8   8 351.0 264 4.22 3.170 14.50  0  1    5    4
Ferrari Dino        19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5    6
Maserati Bora       15.0   8 301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1    5    8
Volvo 142E          21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2
```

Comment: Good solution. I will just add that, and in the spirit of using pipes to avoid typing the input object, the solution can be reduce to `mtcars_matrix %>% base::subset(.[,"hp"] > 100)`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delayed response. You can use the following code,

```
data.frame(mtcars_matrix) %>% dplyr::filter(hp>100)
```